# How can I use NSTextView in block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, nstextview

We know that [Apple Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17)

> Which classes don’t support weak references?
>
> You cannot currently create weak references to instances of the following classes:
>
> NSATSTypesetter, NSColorSpace, NSFont, NSMenuView, NSParagraphStyle, NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter, and NSTextView.
>
> > Note: In addition, in OS X v10.7, you cannot create weak references to instances of NSFontManager, NSFontPanel, NSImage, NSTableCellView, NSViewController, NSWindow, and NSWindowController. In addition, in OS X v10.7 no classes in the AV Foundation framework support weak references.

So the question is `How can use NSTextView in block?`, if don not use weak , the block will hold the strong NSTextView ref.

I'm afraid of the app cannot release the NSTextView.

What should I do?

Comment: you can use __block keyword or if make a property of NSTestView you have to write __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out below :

```
NSTextView * __block textView = [[NSTextView alloc] init…];
```

Adding the __block for this to work out in block and for release purpose you need to explicitly release it in completion block or as per your utilisation.